# calling @Aspect in UnitTest

Tags: spring, unit-testing, annotations, aop, aspectj

I have a Aspect class which is running some method. 
I want to run a Unit Test with the Aspect class included, so it will run the suitable methods. How should I include my Aspect class in my separate Unit Test class, with some annotation or?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class ExampleTest {
```

Comment: If `Application` configuration class correctly enables Aspect handling, there is nothing more you need to do

Comment: Yes, the Aspect is called even through Unit Testing. I made small modification to Point Cut path.

Comment: I might be missing something, but seems to be the problem?

Comment: If your problems is solved, please either delete the question if you made a maistake in your pointcut or write a descriptive answer and self-accept it in order to close the question. Don't just leave the open question dangling around here.